# automatically convert string to appropriate type

Tags: python

I am trying to find a function to have python automatically convert a string to the "simplest" type. Some examples:

```
conversion_function("54") -> returns an int 54
conversion_function("6.34") -> returns a float 6.34
conversion_function("False") -> returns a boolean False
conversion_function("text") -> returns a str "text"
```

R has a function called [type.convert](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/type.convert.html) that does this. What is the way to do this in python? Is there an existing function or does one need to create a custom one?

Comment: You need to create a custom one.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

Comment: `literal_eval` won't handle OP's 4th example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), and fall back to no conversion (returning the original string) if it fails:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

def simplest_type(s):
    try:
        return literal_eval(s)
    except:
        return s
```

Examples:

```py
>>> simplest_type('54')
54
>>> simplest_type('6.34')
6.34
>>> simplest_type('False')
False
>>> simplest_type('text')
'text'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`.

```
import ast
a='[1,2,3]'
b='False'
c='1.2'

print(ast.literal_eval(a),ast.literal_eval(b),ast.literal_eval(c))
```

Note:

> `ast.literal_eval` only works for valid python datatypes.

Comment: Doesn't handle OP's 4th case.

Comment: @ScottHunter Yes, Agreed. I can't think of any different solution than what kaya3 posted. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: You could explain what your note means w.r.t. strings.